# Adding a shader to a gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

How can I add a shader to a game object? a have a shader defined here:

(i am trying to do the same thing and am having some problems): http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/175692/getpixelsetpixels-or-stencil-eraser-brush.html

and 2 texture2D defined in code and loaded through Resource.Load, assigned to a game object. How can I apply the shader to my game object and communicate with the two textures?

As you can see, I have this code in my Shader

```
_MainTex("Main Texture (rgb)", 2D) = "white" {}
_Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
_Stencil("Stencil Texture (a)", 2D) = "white" {}
```

how can I tell the shader who is Main Texture and Stencil Texture?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To apply a shader, you need a material.

You can create a material by clicking 'create' in the project view.

If you use the shader code from the given link, the shader should be in the shader dropdown list in the inspector when selecting a material, under Custom.

You can change the main texture or the other properties through code or in the inspector.

See here:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Material.SetTexture.html